# IResource.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null); is not refreshing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After doing manipulation in my tree viewer, when I'm calling this api **IResource.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);** it is not refreshing the UI. Is there any alternative way by which I can refresh my tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a custom tree viewer that depends on the resource changes, then refreshing the resources will not result in changes in the viewer: the content provider will not be re-executed on resource changes. If you want to refresh a custom viewer, you have to register a resourcechangelistener that will call the refresh or update methods of the viewer.

However, if you are using Common Navigator Framework (CNF) with the built-in resource support, it should refresh itself.

**Update**: The CNF should be configured as follows (that is extracted from my working solution):

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
  <viewerContentBinding 
     viewerId="org.eclipse.viatra2.navigator">
    <includes>
      <contentExtension 
    pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent" />                     
      <contentExtension 
    pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.*"/>
    </includes>
...
</extension>
```

Comment: If you press F5, does the changes appear in the tree?

Comment: I updated my answer to show a working CNF configuration. If your CNF is configured similarly, then I have sadly no further ideas what to check.

Answer (score 1):

For custom models added into Navigator use:

```
if (viewPart instanceof CommonNavigator) {
  CommonViewer viewer = ((CommonNavigator) viewPart).getCommonViewer();
  viewer.refresh();
}
```